# WPF Large Window Header

Tags: wpf, header, ribbon

I'm having a strange problem with a large window header in WPF, dot net 4.5

As you can see, it's much larger than usual:

[image]

**What influences the size of the window header in WPF, and how can I change it?**

The project is giant, if you need any code to look at, please let me know what would be relevant.

Comment: which/what ribbon control do you use? I'm using Microsoft's Ribbon UI, and I haven't experienced any problems you have.

Comment: Fluent Ribbon Control Suite 2.1

Comment: OK. I have downloaded the Fluent Ribbon Control from Codeplex and tried it. Still I can't reproduce your problem. Could you post the XAML code?

Comment: Tell me, did you download Source and build it? The latest "Download" link is not the latest version... @eriawan

Comment: ok I've downloaded the source. I'm investigating it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is that in the **Fluent Ribbon** library with the **Metro Style** you need to have the ribbon be far up off the top of the window in the designer. This is about `-30` margin you must set for vertical. This moves the ribbon up to consume that header space and actually look like a beautiful ribbon window.